# Why am I not able to clone my GIT repository on my EC2 instance?

Tags: ubuntu, github, amazon-ec2

I am trying to clone my GIT repository on a EC2 instance which has ubuntu running. When I fire the command

`git clone <repo_name>`, it sits there for some time and then throw an error as below:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https:<GIT_REPO>':                                                                                         Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Connection timed out.
```

So, I assumed that somehow the port 443 ain't working. So to cross check my open ports, I fired the below command.

```
netstat -tulnp | grep 443
```

It returned to the CLI without any output. Therefore, I tried to open the port as below.

```
 ufw allow 443
```

I received below output

```
Skipping adding existing rule
Skipping adding existing rule (v6)
```

So, I am not sure what to look for now. Furthermore, I checked my EC2 instance network settings. I have attached a screenshot, may be somebody could help me with the root cause.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ping Google.com,check if ping is working then issue some thing else, otherwise instance is in private subnet with out NAT

Comment: Not able to ping google.com from the instance. Please suggest about the private subnet. How to verify and resolve it.

Comment: You attached NAT gateway or launch the instance in public subnet, if this development phase as NAT will gateway will charge

Answer (score 0):

I got it resolved. In the VPC, "ALL TRAFIC" was in a denied state. So, changed the state from DENY to ALLOW. That resolved the issue. However, there is one thing that still confuses me. Since I have explicitly opened the 443 port as shown in my screenshots, then everything on the port 443 should have worked.